# how can I access S3 using jets3t?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jets3t

Hi, I'm trying to access **S3** using **jets3t** library. 
I just followed an sample code supported by AWS([here's url](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html))
here's my simple code

```
import org.jets3t.service.S3Service;
import org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException;
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service;
import org.jets3t.service.model.S3Bucket;
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials;

public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String awsAccessKey = "******************";
    String awsSecretKey = "*********************************";

    System.out.println("0");
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

    try{
    S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials);

    System.out.println("1");

    S3Bucket testBucket = s3Service.getOrCreateBucket("first_test_bucket");
    System.out.println("Created test bucket: " + testBucket.getName());

    S3Bucket[] myBuckets = s3Service.listAllBuckets();

    System.out.println("2");

    System.out.println("How many buckets to I have in S3? " + myBuckets.length);

    System.out.println("3");

    }
    catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println("exception: " + e.toString());

    }

}
```

}

**but I encountered an problem like this**

```
0
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getBoolProperty:315) - s3service.https-only=true
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - storage-service.internal-error-retry-max=5
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - httpclient.connection-timeout-ms=60000
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - httpclient.socket-timeout-ms=60000
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getBoolProperty:315) - httpclient.stale-checking-enabled=true
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - httpclient.max-connections=20
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - httpclient.max-connections-per-host=0
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - httpclient.useragent=null
15:24:39 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils - initHttpConnection:320) - Setting user agent string: JetS3t/0.8.0 (Windows 7/6.1; x86; ko; JVM 1.6.0_20)
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - httpclient.retry-max=5
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getLongProperty:279) - httpclient.connection-manager-timeout=0
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=null
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.default-storage-class=null
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getBoolProperty:315) - httpclient.proxy-autodetect=true
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - devpay.user-token=null
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - devpay.product-token=null
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getBoolProperty:315) - httpclient.requester-pays-buckets-enabled=false
1
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.default-bucket-location=US
15:24:39 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - listAllBucketsImpl:1180) - Listing all buckets for user: AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getBoolProperty:315) - s3service.disable-dns-buckets=false
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint-virtual-path=
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getIntProperty:297) - s3service.s3-endpoint-https-port=443
15:24:39 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - setupConnection:1053) - S3 URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/
15:24:39 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - performRequest:340) - Performing GET request for 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/', expecting response codes: [200]
15:24:39 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:24:39 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:24:39 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:24:39 GMT|/
15:25:01 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils$1 - retryMethod:345) - Retrying GET request with path '/' - attempt 1 of 5
15:25:01 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:25:01 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:25:01 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:25:01 GMT|/
15:25:01  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
15:25:01  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:445) - Retrying request
15:25:22 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils$1 - retryMethod:345) - Retrying GET request with path '/' - attempt 2 of 5
15:25:22 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:25:22 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:25:22 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:25:22 GMT|/
15:25:22  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
15:25:22  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:445) - Retrying request
15:25:43 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils$1 - retryMethod:345) - Retrying GET request with path '/' - attempt 3 of 5
15:25:43 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:25:43 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:25:43 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:25:43 GMT|/
15:25:43  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
15:25:43  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:445) - Retrying request
    15:26:04 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils$1 - retryMethod:345) - Retrying GET request with path '/' - attempt 4 of 5
15:26:04 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:26:04 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:26:04 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:26:04 GMT|/
15:26:04  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
15:26:04  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:445) - Retrying request
15:26:25 DEBUG (utils.RestUtils$1 - retryMethod:345) - Retrying GET request with path '/' - attempt 5 of 5
15:26:25 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:591) - Adding authorization for Access Key 'AKIAI6TCJ7BDPCPTHV2A'.
15:26:25 DEBUG (service.Jets3tProperties - getStringProperty:261) - s3service.s3-endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com
15:26:25 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - authorizeHttpRequest:643) - Canonical string ('|' is a newline): GET|||Wed, 06 Apr 2011 06:26:25 GMT|/
15:26:25  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out: connect
15:26:25  INFO (httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - executeWithRetry:445) - Retrying request
15:26:46 DEBUG (httpclient.RestStorageService - performRequest:538) - Releasing HttpClient connection after error: Connection timed out: connect
exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Request Error. GET '/'
```

**I guess this is a problem about firewall since I'm excuting this code at my company. Does anybody knows this problem? help!**

Comment: I hope that the Access Key and Secret Key are fake...

Comment: your keys are still visible in the older revisions of this post. You better delete this entire thread or better still, Logon to Amazon AWS and change your credentials ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your - not so easy to read - log there are some  "Connection timed out: connect exception: ...". So, yes, it may be because you are behind a proxy (Amazon S3 Rest services listen on port 443).

You may want to configure JetS3t to use a proxy. 
Create a jets3t.properties property file and add the following properties:

```
httpclient.proxy-host=your proxy host
httpclient.proxy-port=your proxy port
httpclient.proxy-user=proxy user
httpclient.proxy-password=password
```

more info here: http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/configuration.html#jets3t

Also, please note that there is a somehow stable S3 test stub that you can use for testing:
https://github.com/technoweenie/parkplace

Comment: Great Thanks, Mr.Luciano and also for your advice ! It's my mistake that exposed my secret, access key! I already deleted key! And I solved this proxy problem although I wandered some issues like adding properties to eclipse project!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the Jets3t configurations in a text file format and give the Jets3t class properties as follows:

```
Jets3tProperties jets3=new Jets3tProperties();
jets3.loadAndReplaceProperties(new FileInputStream("/root/Desktop/jets3t.properties"), "jets3t.properties");
```